# Subsetting dataframe based on dynamically generated checkBoxGroupInput: checkbox keeps resetting

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to use a Shiny app to load a file (tab-separated), dynamically create a `checkboxGroupInput`, after the loading of the file (using `observeEvent`) using the column headers, then subset the data frame that comes from the file based on the selected checkboxes. The data is then plotted using code I can't share right now.

All is working fine, apart from the last bit: subsetting the dataframe based on the selected checkboxes in `checkboxGroupInput`. The checkboxes all start selected, and the plot is created fine. If you un-select one of the checkboxes, the plot re-plots appropriately for a split second (so the subsetting is working fine) **then the unselected checkbox re-selects itself and the plot goes back to the old plot.** 
This is the tiny problem I'm trying to solve, guessing it's one line of code. I'm assuming it's because of some reactivity that I don't understand and the checkbox constantly resetting itself.

Here is an example:

```
###

## Some functions I can't share

### Shiny app
library(shiny)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("MagicPlotter"),

  # Sidebar  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(inputId = "myInputID",
                label = "Your .csv file",
                placeholder = "File not uploaded"),
      uiOutput("mylist"),
      uiOutput("submitbutton")
    ),

    # Show a plot
    mainPanel(
      verticalLayout(
        plotOutput("myPlot"))
    )
  )
)

# Define server
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({



    inputfile <- input$myInputID

    if(is.null(inputfile))
    {return()}
    mydataframe <- read.table(file=inputfile$datapath, sep="\t", head=T, row.names = 1)


    mydataframecolumnnames <- colnames(mydataframe[1:(length(mydataframe)-1)])
    # the last column is dropped because it's not relevant as a column name

    observeEvent(input$myInputID, {
      output$mylist <- renderUI({
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId="mylist",
                           label="List of things to select",
                           choices=mydataframecolumnnames,
                           selected=mydataframecolumnnames)
      })
    })

    observeEvent(input$myInputID, {
      output$submitbutton <- renderUI({
        submitButton("Subset")
      })
    }) 

    mysubset <- mydataframe[input$mylist]

    myPlot(mysubset)

  })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few things that might help...

One, you can move your `observeEvent` methods outside of your `renderPlot`.

Also, you can create a `reactive` function to read in the data table.

I hope this helps.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  myDataFrame <- reactive({
    inputfile <- input$myInputID
    if(is.null(inputfile))
      {return()}
    read.table(file=inputfile$datapath, sep="\t", head=T, row.names = 1)
  })

  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$mylist)
    mysubset <- myDataFrame()[input$mylist]
    plot(mysubset)
  })

  observeEvent(input$myInputID, {
   mydata <- myDataFrame()
   mydataframecolumnnames <- colnames(mydata[1:(length(mydata)-1)])

   output$mylist <- renderUI({
     checkboxGroupInput(inputId="mylist",
                        label="List of things to select",
                        choices=mydataframecolumnnames,
                        selected=mydataframecolumnnames)
   })
  })

  observeEvent(input$myInputID, {
   output$submitbutton <- renderUI({
     submitButton("Subset")
   })
  }) 

}
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. I think I understand the logic of what you did there.